# How to implement JQuery confirm dialog popup

Tags: python, django

I have a form with a submit button ant I want to add a confirm modal dialog
using JQuery example without success when I use django template

I currently used the JS confirm() (see below) but I would like to customize the dialog box
I have understand that I should use a JQuery Dialog so I try to implement this solution

this is my template:

```py
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block extrahead %}
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#randomize").click(function(event){
                var response = confirm("Do you confirm randomization");
                if (response == false) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Index | Intense TBM{% endblock %}
{% block content %}



<div class='container'>

<h1>Randomization form</h1>
</br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <strong>Patient code: </strong>{{ preincluded.pat_num }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        <strong>Age: </strong>{{ preincluded.age }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        <strong>Sex: </strong>
        {% if preincluded.pat_sex == 1 %}
            Male
        {% else %}
            Female
        {% endif %}

    </div>
</br></br>
</div>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form |crispy }}
        <!--<button id="randomize" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirm('Do you confirm randomization?')">Randomize</button>-->
        <button id="randomize" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Randomize</button>
    </form>

</div>
</br></br></br></br>

{% endblock %}
```

I try to change the JS code with this:

```py
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#randomize").click(function(event){
            $('body').append('<div id="dialog"></div>');
            $("#dialog").html('Do you confirm randomization?');

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                title: 'Intense TBM Randomization',
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function() {
                        //
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        //
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    });
  </script>
```

**EDIT
Infact I have an message error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'**

If I inspect my page with dev tool I can see that the div #dialog is added but the dialog box did not show

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting the dialog div#dialog dynamically to the dom but jquery is not aware of this. Jquery doesn't find the div#dialog on the dom so it threw error.

All you have to do is intialize the div#dialog at page load, so it will present on dom.

You have to make style display:none css to the div#dialog so it doesn't show up unless you actually want to show.

To show up, you can just use $('#dialog').show() and call hide() when you want toggle.

Comment: I tried with <div id="dialog"></div> (empty) at page load and add text on click button but it doesn't work ; I have the same error maybe i did not understand what you said?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a 'simpliest' example and i works!
I am lost !!!

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#randomize").click(function(event){
            //afficher popup -> créer une fonction et ajouter le numéor du patient en paramètre 
            //pour personnaliser le popup
            $('body').append('<div id="dialog"></div>');
            $("#dialog").html('Do you confirm randomization?');
            console.log($('#dialog'))
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                title: 'Intense TBM Randomization',
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function() {
                        //
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        //
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    });

  // $( function() {
  //   $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  // } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="randomize" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Randomize</button> 



</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem
I need to add jQuery.noConflict();